# New GFX card, monitor doesn't turn on

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

I just got an Nvidia Geforce GFX 260 - http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-260/specifications

The specs say that the minimum power requirement is 500W.

When I plug in my gfx card, the computer boots up - I don't hear any 'abnormal' BIOS beeps, but my monitor doesn't come on.

How do I know if my system has enough power to send to the GFX card?

Or rather...does this sound like what would happen if the GFX card is not getting enough power?

I have maxed out my RAM slots - 6GB over 4 slots. I have 2 hard drives, 2 DVD Drives, 1 Network Card, and 1 USB expansion card.

Suffice it to say, I am using up a lot of the power from the PSU....so if it is that I don't have enough power, I wouldn't be surprised.

Thoughts?

P.S. For what it's worth, the card only has 2 DVI outputs and I only have a VGA monitor - so I got a DVI-to-VGA adapter. I doubt that would cause this issue, but figured I would throw it in there just in case there is some strange quirk that I don't know about.

Comment: If you don't have enough power, it is likely that your system would shut off instantly. Since when you don't have enough power, you don't have enough power for *all* components. Are you sure you connected all required power connectors to the card?

Comment: However, in this context, it would also be interesting which wattage your PSU has :)

Comment: I think I did. Either way, I took it out and reseated the card and it has worked. If you write that as an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: If you were able to fix your problem yourself, you can also write your own answer and accept it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply re-seated the GFX card and it works fine now.